# Can I use DATE as partition key in Azure Table?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

I want to create Azure Table for transaction and I want to use the DATE as partition key. Can I use DATE as partition key in Azure Table? and Do I need to convert the date to string vice versa if I need to use it in my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `PartitionKey` attribute is of type `String`, you would need to convert the date/time into string. Again please keep in mind that entities are sorted on `PartitionKey` (and `RowKey`) alphabetically, you want to ensure that when you convert to string, you format in a way so that entities are returned in a desirable order. I would recommend converting them to string using `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss` format so that new orders are always appended.

Comment: I'd disagree with proposed format, because of accurancy to second only. I think, it's better to use the same pattern as being used in WAD Logs:  string invertedTicks = string.Format("{0:D19}", DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks - DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks)

Comment: My concern with partioning using the seconds is that you gonna have thousands of partitions,  Should you not just user date for partion key?

Answer (score 6):

The answer is yes you can but date is more commonly used as the RowKey value. The partition key is used to logically group rows that are related. This causes them to be stored in the same local region even though they might be spread across multiple virtual machines. By doing this you can achieve high performance when retrieving them and more importantly you can act (insert/update/delete) on multiple rows in a transaction if they share a partition.

RowKey while not required to be unique within a table is unique when paired with PartitionKey. Think of it as a two column primary key. Rowkey is often a date type stored as a string and the recommended pattern in yearmonthday like January 29th 2015 would be 20150129.

Used together these two keys provide high speed access to the table. If not used a table scan is the result which is much slower.

A better way to use partition key is to generate it off of some static property of your system. For example if you had 1000 weather stations reporting data constantly every day you might use a stationId as the PartitionKey and date as the RowKey.

This also has the added benefit of more evenly organizing your rows among partitions so that they are relatively of equal size. This helps Azure storage more evenly distribute the partitions and do a better job of load balancing.

Comment: Thank you daustinash for the answer

Answer (score 3):

You can, as Gaurav Mantri mentions above. Note however, that this may result in bad performance because of the "Append Only" pattern that you are setting up: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-performance-checklist/#subheading28

Azure Storage learns your usage pattern, and adjusts the partition distribution according to the load, adaptively. So if you have your load across a number of partition keys, then it can split those partitions into different servers internally, to balance your load. However, if you load is all on one partition, and that partition changes periodically (like it does with append-only pattern), then the adaptive load balancing logic gets ineffective. To avoid this, you should avoid using dates or date-times as your partition key, if your query patterns allow it.

Comment: What mechanism would you suggest them? I have a case where we are logging a stream of device logs, so would fall into the "Append Only" pattern. However we require superior query / read performance based on date field.  (Do i just do a random number between 1 and 100 for the partition key)?

Comment: Late answer, but from your description, I would use your device's ID as the partitionKey and datetime (string format) as rowKey.